# Jsoup on imdb 403 error

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I need to parse the imdb page in order to get results displayed. I am using Jsoup for this purpose. Below is the code that I wrote for this purpose. When I run the code, I see a 403 error. I re-verified the url and the url seems to be right.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class ParseIMDB {

    public static void parse() throws IOException{
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://imdb.com/search/title?count=100&genres=action&languages=en&release_date=2010,2016&title_type=feature").get();
        Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#main > table.results tbody");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
        parse();
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception found!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried encoding the url using URLEncode.encode but it dint help either.

The stack trace for the above code is as below:

> Exception found! org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching
>   URL. Status=403, URL=http://www.imdb.com/search/title/    at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:537)
>     at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:534)
>     at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
>     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
>     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194)     at
>   ParseIMDB.parse(ParseIMDB.java:13)    at
>   ParseIMDB.main(ParseIMDB.java:20)

Comment: I actually get a 301 (Moved Permanently) when I try that URL with curl. Adding `www` makes curl return the page at least. Not sure that helps.

Comment: Did you try adding `www` in your code? My browser automatically adds `www` so it might be required.

Comment: I tried with www and it does not seem to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it'll work if you add a `User-Agent` header to the request. You can do that like this:

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://imdb.com/search/title?count=100&genres=action&languages=en&release_date=2010,2016&title_type=feature")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36")
                .get();
```

This solution has been tested and works, returning a list of movies.

Answer (score 0):

`HTTP 403` means *Forbidden*. Most likely imdb is blocking programmatic requests.